# Where does classpath ends and starts?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

What is meant by saying project is on the classpath? For example, I keep a file within project directory (Project/file), is that on the classpath? How should I know what the classpath involves in my project? 
I am trying to read text file by using InputStream object. The idea is to read the file whilst you are running the jar file (the app). As far as I know in case of InputStream object the file shall be on the classpath. So, where does the file supposed to be? I am developing on Eclipse IDE.
Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more specifics. Are you talking about in the context of an IDE? Inside a jar file? *Where* inside a jar file, and how are you trying to access it (assuming you're still working on the text file as input stream issue)?

Comment: The CLASSPATH is what you say it is.  If you didn't state it, it's not on the CLASSPATH.  It sounds like you're making assumptions about behavior that don't appear to be true.  If that's so, it's time to check your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

The project's Java Build Path determines what your project's sources consider to be on their CLASSPATH, as well as what's used when launching applications in that project.  If you're running a .jar externally, it's what you've set in that environmental variable or with the -classpath/-cp arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Classpath during eclipse development is determined by `Configure Build Path` dialog. Classpath during runtime is determined by runtime conditions. In eclipse it is done by `Run (or Debug) configurations` dialog. If you deploy your application somewhere, then classpath is determined by conditions at deployment place.